# Macro / keyword which can be used to print out method name?

Tags: c++, c

`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are well known. There is a `__func__` since C99.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
        void Do(){ std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
        std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
        Foo foo; foo.Do();
        return 0;
}
```

will output

```
main
Do
```

Is there any macro / keyword that would output method name like `Foo::Do`?

Comment: Cannot decide on the best answer. I click something, and I apologize to the rest :-).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Boost has a special utility macro called [BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/current_function.html) that hides the differences between the compiler implementations.

Following it's implementation we see that there are several macros depending on compiler:

- `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` -- GCC, MetroWerks, Digital Mars, ICC, MinGW
- `__FUNCSIG__` -- MSVC
- `__FUNCTION__` -- Intel and IBM
- `__FUNC__` -- Borland
- `__func__` -- ANSI C99

Comment: +1 for presenting a solution that works on multiple platforms

Comment: +1.  This is an excellent solution.  I hadn't discovered this yet.

Comment: the problem with Boost is that often times it has solutions for things you did not even thought about. I did not think it was "possible" and therefore I did not try to look it up...

Comment: One more option: Q_FUNC_INFO if one uses Qt.

Answer (score 10):

- On GCC you can use `__FUNCTION__` and
  `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.
- On MSVC you can use `__FUNCSIG__` and `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is awesome! Will test `__FUNCSIG__` later.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such macro in standard C++, and that includes the draft C++0x standard I looked at.  It would complicate compilation, since parsing (necessary to determine what a function is) comes after preprocessing, and I suspect that's why there's nothing in the standard.

The `__func__` you're using is nonstandard, although it apparently works on your compiler.

Comment: This is of course nonsense as it can insert an implementation defined runtime function. Preprocessor String concatanation would then impossible but it's not allowed for other preprocessor symbols either.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Standard C++ (and `__func__` is not part of C++). Your implementation may have such a feature though - which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm interested in g++ and MSVC++ too.

Answer (score 1):

See "[Predefined Macros (C/C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx)" for a complete list supported by MS Visual Studio.

Comment: That document lives here, now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
int main()
{
printf("line number is %d .. func name is %s, file name is %s",__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__);
return  0;
}
```

This is how to print line number, function name and file name in gcc.