# Is there an effective way in C++ to retrieve *full signature* of a function at run-time?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro / keyword which can be used to print out method name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192680/macro-keyword-which-can-be-used-to-print-out-method-name)

Is there an effective way in C++ to retrieve *full signature* of a function at run-time?

I need this for logging purpose. I'm aware of macro like `__FUNCTION__`, but doesn't serve the purpose as it just returns the function names. There could be many overloaded versions of same function, I want to log the full function signature. I'm looking for a solution that work correctly if even function signature is modified. The solution should always log the current function signature

```
void log(const char* const message)    
    {
        cout << message << endl;
    }

    void ABC(const int& number)
    {
        Log(???); // what should I pass to this function so full signature of the ABC function is logged??
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to print the parameter names (e.g. "number") or the parameter values (e.g. "42")?

Comment: Parameter values are not part of the signature...

Comment: Yes, I want full signature. With above example, output should be "void ABC(const int& number)"

Comment: Take a look at this blog: [How to get function's name from function's pointer in C? (Windows)](http://ivbel.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-get-functions-name-from.html)
It shows that if you link with Dbghelp.lib and use `SymGetSymFromAddr64` you can get the full signature of a function at run-time... also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205981/windows-c-stack-trace-from-a-running-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Predefined Macros (C/C++) page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has a list of all the available macros. The one you are looking for is, likely, `__FUNCSIG__`.

Comment: I like this better than the answer I had, which I've deleted

Answer (score 1):

In general there is not, but if using GCC you could use the [`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) pseudo macro....

```
 void ABC(const int& number) {
     Log(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
     /// etc...
 }
```

The Clang/LLVM compiler also has it.

Comment: I'm using visual studio compile. __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ doesn't work...

Comment: Might be a good reason to try GCC ....