# Is performance hit by using Caller Information attributes?

Tags: c#, performance, logging, .net-4.5

I am trying to find ways to log method name in an efficient manner w.r.t. speed and maintainability. I guess, In .NET 4.5 [Caller Information attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) are exposed just for this purpose except the speed part. I feel these are just syntactic sugars from using `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` or `stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name` (Got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)). (or) Are these methods give performance benefits too?

In C#, Is there a way to get method name at compile time (as like in [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192680/macro-keyword-which-can-be-used-to-print-out-method-name))?

Comment: Have you actually profiled their performance, or are you simply pre-empting an issue that may not be an issue?

Comment: @DanielKelley I have not measured the performance. I wanted to know what is happening under the covers of Caller Information attributes. Daniel mentioned that the replacement happens at compile time which is exactly I am looking for.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The caller information attributes cause the C# compiler to supply the caller's name at the callsite. This happens at compile-time, there is no reflection involved.

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    LogCall();
}

public void LogCall([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
     Console.WriteLine(memberName + " was called.");
}
```

Will be compiled to:

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    LogCall("DoProcessing");
}

public void LogCall(string memberName)
{
     Console.WriteLine(memberName + " was called.");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for your quick response. Do you have any idea to achieve the compile time replacement in the older versions of .NET?

Comment: [CallerMemberInfo] will work with any .NET version as long as you use the C# 5 compiler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381917/is-the-callermembername-attribute-in-4-5-able-to-be-faked

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not presently using c# 5 compiler which requires VS2012.