# How to implement C++ macros (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCSIG__, and so forth) in Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi

Some C++ code have used  [useful macros/variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192680/macro-keyword-which-can-be-used-to-print-out-method-name)  such as :

```
 __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCSIG__, and so forth
```

Are there equivalent functionalities in Delphi ? 
If not, how should one implement custom functions to provide equivalent functionalities ?

Comment: Fundamentally, Delphi has nothing like these macros. The best you can do is implement bespoke solutions to whatever your problem is. But there are no drop in equivalents.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In the "dup" link that you have helped to provide, you mention that "If you use this as a debugging tool to trace errors you will seriously degrade the quality and maintainability of your source code and you will have a rather pathetic and crippled debugging tool in comparison to madExcept or other similar tools." I probably should just neglect those lines when reading C++ code...

Comment: I am referring to code littered with Assert statements to fake line number getters. C++ code using the macros is readable.

Comment: For your information, FPC [has such macros](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/prog/progsu41.html), and you can even [define your own set](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/prog/progse5.html) .